# Shortcut to open "pinned programs" in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, shortcuts

when I hit the Start button, it will show me a couple of *pinned programs*:

[image]

So, basically, is there a fast shortcut key that I can use to open Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to create one.  To do this, right-click on the icon (in your Start Menu under the "Programs" section), then click on the field next to "Shortcut key" and press the desired keystrokes you wish to use.

The following screenshot highlights where you can find this option in a shortcut's properties:

[image]

Comment: heys how do i access the screen if its not in my program files folder -> C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Comment: @Pacerier:  I don't understand what you're asking.  (You can always create a shortcut by right-clicking on that .exe file, then configure your shortcut key from that shortcut -- make sure you move that shortcut somewhere safe, like into your Start Menu somewhere.)

Comment: it doesn't give me the option to shortcut key when i right click that .exe: http://i.imgur.com/vRzK6.gif

Comment: @Pacerier:  No, it won't.  Due to inherent Windows GUI design limitations, you can only do that for shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

If you press the down arrow key, Chrome will be highlighted. So, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> in succession to launch Chrome.

Comment: Note:  This assumes that "Chrome" is the first item in the Start Menu (and it is a reasonable solution).

Comment: cool! this is actually what I'm looking for. but i found a better solution above